# If $k$ cannot equal $0$ and $A$ is as given below, what is $A$ inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 2k\\
0 & 1 & k\\
0 & 0 & k
}
$$

I don't know what method to use to solve this problem as I haven't encountered and variable before when solving for the inverse of a matrix. I've tried to use the identity method to solve it. It didn't seem right. I also, tried solving for each row and setting them equal to 0, this also didn't seem right.

Comment: Thanks , I appreciate all the different methods, it has broadened my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the row-reduction method, we try to bring the augmented block matrix $(A|I)$ to the form  $(I|A^{-1})$. In this case, that is fairly simple:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}1&0&2k&1&0&0\\0&1&k&0&1&0\\0&0&k&0&0&1\end{array}\right) \to \left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}1&0&0&1&0&-2\\0&1&0&0&1&-1\\0&0&1&0&0&\tfrac{1}{k}\end{array}\right)
$$
So that your inverse should be 
$$
A^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&-2\\0&1&-1\\0&0&\tfrac{1}{k}\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: ok, I actually did get this answer. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Alec can I get a link to the row reduction method here?

Comment: @Sabyasachi The row reduction method is equivalent to solving the systems $Ax_1=e_1,$ $Ax_2=e_2$ etc, which is finding the columns of $A^{-1}$ one at a time.

Comment: @Sabyasachi [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianElimination.html)

Comment: @RR thanks a lot.

Comment: @mookid great. thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: We can write the matrix as the product of [elementary matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2k \\
0 & 1 & k \\
0 & 0 & k \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & k \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Perhaps you'll find it easier to find $$
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & k \\
\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & k \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.
$$
Their inverses are described on the linked wikipedia page.

Comment: very helpful thank you

Answer (score 1):

Apply Gauss Method:

$\left[\begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 & 2k & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & k  & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & k  & 0 & 0 & 1
 \end{matrix}\right]$

$\left[\begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 & 0  & 1 & 0 & -2\\
  0 & 1 & 0  & 0 & 1 & -1\\
  0 & 0 & k  & 0 & 0 & 1
 \end{matrix}\right]$

$\left[\begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 & 2k & 1 & 0 & -2\\
  0 & 1 & k  & 0 & 1 & -1\\
  0 & 0 & 1  & 0 & 0 & \frac 1k
 \end{matrix}\right]$

so the inverse is
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
 1 & 0 & -2\\
 0 & 1 & -1\\
 0 & 0 & \frac 1k
 \end{matrix}\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

The first two columns of $A$ are already the columns of an identity matrix, so the first two columns of $A^{-1}$ will be these as well. To finish finding $A^{-1}$ you need to find the last column, which can be done by solving $Ax=e_3$ for $x$, where $e_3$ is the third column of the identity matrix. Once you have constructed this, verify that $AA^{-1}$ gives you the identity by direct computation.

Comment: I see I'm going to work it out with this method as well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try solving $Ax_k = e_k$ for $x_k$, where $e_1 = (1,0,0)^T$, etc. Then form the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{bmatrix}$.

For example, we see that $x_3 = (-2,-1,{1 \over k})^T$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the formula $A^{-1}=$$1\over detA)$$(A^t)^*$

$det (A)=k$

$A^t=\matrix {1 &0& k \\ 0&1&0\\2 k&k &k}$

Now we calculate the adjunted matrix $|A_{11}|=|\matrix{1&0\\ k&k}|=k$ ,...,$|A_{33}|=|\matrix{1&0\\ 0&1}|=1$

So, $(A^t)^*= \matrix{k&0&-2k\\ 0&k&-k\\0&0&1}$

Finally, $A^{-1}= \matrix{1&0&-2\\ 0&1&-1\\0&0&1/k}$

Comment: this is almost always the wrong way to inverse a matrix.

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: I have seen matrices solved this way before that didn't include any variables, I do believe this is the longest method though.

Comment: @Triana: It make way too many computations to do: you have to compute $n\times n$ determinants, which is very long.

Comment: For a square matrix with $n$ columns this approach tends to take at least $n!$ flops, which is far larger than the roughly $n^3$ from the row reduction method. For very large matrices using this approach on a computer (let alone by hand) would be out of the question.

Comment: Yes, that's true when n is a big number, but in the case n=2, n=3 it is something trivial. It may be longer than the others but it is not wrong @mookid. I just wanted to write down another option to solve this problem.

Comment: For the $3\times 3$ case, this is already messy, just consider the computation of the whole matrix (here it is immediate, but not in the general case). Then you have to compute the 9 small determinants, I think it is too much. But this is just my point of view!